# Spring Kafka consumer parse JSON as String

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka to consume the messages from a topic. Below is the structure of the object which will be listened to by the consumer.

```
{
  "identifier": "ABCD1234",
  "data": {
            "id": 12345,
            "source": 'Dashboard',
            "status": 'SUCCESS',
        }
}
```

To consume such objects, I need to use JsonDeserilizer. But the concern is the data part of this JSON will not be fixed. It may have a different structure. The producer will send the data in any other format where properties will be different than the ones mentioned above.

If I have to create JsonDeserlizer then I need to map individual properties to the Java model class. I think parsing the `data` as a String will simplify the things

This is the code I am using right now. But it parses everything as a String.

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getConsumerBootstrapServers());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID_CONFIG);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
            new StringDeserializer());
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

How can I parse the data field as a String? In simpler words, parse the entire object using JsonDeserilizer but parse the `data` field as a String.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a class like this to parse,

```
public class MainObject {
    private String identifier;
    private String data;
}
```

`data` filed will contain your JSON object as a string. Then you can use something like `ObjectMapper` to de-serialize it.

#### Update

As @OneCricketeer has mentioned you can also use `JsonNode`.

```
public class MainObject {
    private String identifier;
    private JsonNode data;
}
```

It is more useful if you cannot figure out what is in there in `data` field using anything already available in the `MainObject`.

Comment: Okay but what would be the deserializer in consumer factory?

Comment: `JsonDeserilizer` of course. I wonder how you can figure out what will be there in `data` field? Do you use  value in `identifier` field?

Comment: You should use `JsonNode data`